# Use flex to uppercase C comments

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

I want to uppercase C comments in a text using flex.

Here is my flex code：

```
%{
#include <ctype.h>
%}

%%

\/\/.* {
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(yytext); i++)
        printf("%c", toupper(yytext[i]));   
}

\/\*[^\*]*\*(\*|[^\*\/][^\*]*)*\/ {
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(yytext); i++)
        printf("%c", toupper(yytext[i]));
}

%%

int main(int argc ,char* argv[]) {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the testing text:

```
/*aBc*aBc/aBc*/
/** /aBc*/
/*aBc*/aBc*/
aBc
aBc/*aBC
aBc/aBc*aBc
aBc**/
/*aBc/*aBc
//aBc
//aBc
aBc
```

The result:

```
/*ABC*ABC/ABC*/
/** /ABC*/
/*ABC*/aBc*/
aBc
aBc/*ABC
ABC/ABC*ABC
ABC**/
/*ABC/*ABC
//ABC
//aBc
aBc
```

The second and fourth line from the end in the result are weird.

What's wrong with my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that the regular expression you are using is incorrect.

Here's a correct flex regular expression for C-style comments:

```
"/*"[^*]*"*"+([^*/][^*]*"*"+)*"/"
```

That uses double-quotes (a flex feature) to quote the regex metacharacters. Note that it is not necessary to escape regex operators inside character classes.

The alternatives aren't very pretty either:

1. Forest of leaning timber:

   ```
   \/\*[^*]*\*+([^*/][^*]*\*+)*\/
   ```
2. Clutter of character classes:

   ```
   [/][*][^*]*[*]+([^*/][^*]*[*]+)*[/]
   ```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I rewrite the regex from DFA and find that a "*" is missed. Oops... Now it is `\/\*[^\*]*\*(\*|[^\*\/][^\*]*\*)*\/` which may have the same effect with the regex you wirte.

Comment: The escape of meta characters such as "*" is optional inside character classes.

Comment: @chaosink; Yes, that is what "not necessary" means. In Posix regexes, it is not allowed, but flex is more generous. I always recommend against it, though, because it does not improve readability IMHO, and you may someday want to use the regex in a dialect which doesn't allow the escapes.

Comment: Your (new) regex includes γ(γ |ωγ)* (where γ is an asterisk and ω is anything other than slash or asterisk, followed by any number of non-asterisks). (γ |ωγ)* is equivalent to (ω?γ)* which in turn is equivalent to γ*(ωγ+)*. So γ(γ |ωγ)* can be rewritten as γ+(ωγ+)*. That's the same as my regex. FWIW.

Comment: I'm doubt that (ω?γ)* is equivalent to γ*(ωγ+)*. How can I get γωγγ from the latter? By the way, is there a boot that talks about the simplification or equivalence of regex?

Comment: γ* -> γ; (ωγ+)* ->  ωγ+ ->  ωγγ